# Merging numeric and characters from different datasets

Tags: r, merge

I am trying to combine two datasets.
Dataset 1 has ca. 4000 rows and Dataset 2 has 132 rows. I want to match the `Brand` names in Dataset 2 with the `UPS` one in dataset 1. So All the `UPS` have the corresponding `Brands` in 1 as well. I tried to merge them both with `merge`. However, I have been so far unsuccessful of merging them.

DataSet 01:
Where UPS is numeric

```
  UPS         WEEK  AP
1 1111112016    1   385.22
2 1111112016    2   221.63
3 1111112016    3   317.47
4 1111112016    4   173.71
5 1111112016    5   269.55
```

Dataset 02:

```
  UPC        Brand
1 1111112016 Dove
2 1111112440 Dove
3 1111112480 Dove
4 1111112501 Dove
5 1111132008 Lever
6 1111132012 Lever
7 1111132048 Lever
8 1111132122 Lever
```

This is how i tried it so far:

```
Brand = c(unique(UB$Brand))
UPS = c(unique(PAW2$UPS))
PAWn = merge(PAW, UB, by.x = "UPS", by.y = "Brand")
```

I am aware that there are other posts out there. But so far they did not help.

Comment: Shouldn't be `by.y = "UPC"`? You got nothing because the `UPS` column of `PAW` is of course never equal to the `Brand` column of `UB`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your description, I think you need:

```
 merge(PAW, UB, by.x = "UPS", by.y = "UPC", all.x = TRUE)
```

to get what you want. As Nicola already said in the comments, the only way you can match the `Brand` names in `UB` to the `UPS` codes in `PAW` is via matching with the `UPC` codes in `UB`.

This also works when `UB$UPC` is a character variable and `PAW$UPS` is a numeric variable.

By adding `all.x = TRUE` all observations in `PAW` are returned, even when they don't have matching values in `UB`.

Comment: I tried that and i still get the error:Error in fix.by(by.y, y) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column

Comment: It works on the example data you provided in the question. What are your column names?

Comment: I was able to resolve it. It seems that one does not need to assign specific values for the merging arguments, which are later used `by.x` or `by.y`. You just can say which column should be chosen. I just said    PAW_N = merge(PAW, UB, by.x = "UPS", by.y = "UPC", all.x = TRUE)